# Parabola equation from cartesian to polar representation

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates

I've got the following equation:
0) $ \frac{(y-y_p)^{2}}{4\cdot(x-x_p)} = p $

I'd like now to convert this expression to a polar representation. 
For this I got back to the basic rules:
1)  $x = r\cdot cos\theta$
2) $y = r\cdot sin \theta$
3) $r = \sqrt{x^{2}+y{2} }$
4) $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

Applying rule 1) and 2) to y and x only, we get:
$\frac{(r\cdot sin \theta-y_p)^{2}}{4\cdot(r\cdot cos\theta-x_p)} = p$

Now I got stuck with the following question: how are the parameters $x_p$, $y_p$ and $p$
treated?

However I'm thinking that my approach is wrong or that at least something is missing in order to fully convert equation 0) to polar coordinates.

Thank you in advance for any hints and
with best regards
Dan

Answer (score 1):

HINT
$$
 \frac{(y-y_p)^{2}}{4\cdot(x-x_p)} = p 
$$
and substituting $y-y_p=r\sin\theta$ and $x-x_p=\cos\theta$, you'll find
$$
r(\theta)=4p\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}
$$

Answer (score 0):

extracting variables $x,y$, we obtain
$$\frac{(y-y_p)^2}{4(x-x_p)}=p$$
The trick consists on performing the polar transformation on the point $(x_p,y_p)$. Then $y-y_p=r\sin\theta$ and $x-x_p=r\cos\theta$. Finding
$$r\tan(\theta)\sin(\theta)=4p$$

Comment: Yes, thank you @mathlove . Correcting

Comment: This seems to confuse the (unfortunately named...) constant $yp$ with the product $y \cdot p$.

Comment: @Travis absolutely. I've edited it.

Comment: Yes, I suposed $yp=y*p$. Is it not true? It is kind of confusing this question. Thank you for the remark!

Comment: @seoanes: Thank you for your answer! I've indeed caused a bad confusion with xp and yp. ...$x_p$, $y_p$ and $p$ are the parameters where I am not sure how to treat them in order to transform them in polar representation. :)